# How do I solve $Mx = y$ if $M$ is singular?

Tags: matrix-equations

Ok so I remember this trick that you could sometimes use to solve $Mx = y$ for $x$, given $M$ and $y$. It did not invovle computing $M^{-1}$. Can you remind me what it was?

The only thing I remember is that you would do something to the equation $Mx = y$ such that you would get a new equation $$M' x = y'$$ where $M'$ and $y'$ are different from before. And then, it turns out that $M'$ is always invertible, and then you could find the inverse.

What was that trick?

EDIT:  I know there are million times more efficient ways to do this that does not involve finding inverses. Not asking about that.

Comment: You can't “solve” a singular system, as you point out.  But the least-squares method provides the closest *approximation* to a solution.

Answer (score 4):

My best guess is that you're thinking of [linear least-squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#The_general_problem).  Given the (usually overdetermined) system $Mx = y$, we can "multiply both sides by $M^T$" to get the least-squares equation
$$
(M^TM)\hat x = (M^Ty)
$$
and a solution $\hat x$ is known as a *least-squares solution* to $Mx = y$.  If the columns of $M$ are linearly independent (i.e. if $M$ has full column-rank), then $M^TM$ is invertible and we have the unique least-squares solution
$$
\hat x = (M^TM)^{-1}(M^Ty)
$$
It is not necessarily true that $M' = M^TM$ is invertible.  However, it is always true that this new system of equations will necessarily have at least one solution.

---

Notably, the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Definition) calculates "inverses" to singular matrices with this least-squares idea in mind.  In particular, if $Mx = y$, then $M^+y$ is the least-squares solution $\hat x$ such that $\|\hat x\|$ is minimized.